# HTML 5 canvas shape collision Test

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Can you please help me with my collision test .

In flash I would use a Hittest and it would take 2 minutes to do but as I see HTML5 is a little different.

Below is my code. I can make the ball bounce inside the red block easily but I want a grey block in the middle that  the ball bounces off also and the if statement is getting messy and not working. Is there an easier way todo this, can you please help me. Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<script>
    var context;
    var x=50;
    var y=100;
    var speedX=-2;
    var speedY=-2;
    var counter=0;
    var ballCoordinates ='';

    function init()
    {
      var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      context= c.getContext('2d');
      setInterval(draw,10);
    }

    function draw()
    {
          context.clearRect(0,0, 300,400);

          //draw number
          context.fillStyle = '#fff';
          context.font="160px Arial";
          context.fillText(counter,10,150);

          context.fillStyle = '#fff';
          context.font="20px Arial";
          context.fillText(ballCoordinates,10,400);

          //draw ball
          context.beginPath();
          context.fillStyle="#0000ff";
          context.arc(x,y,20,0,Math.PI*2,true);
          context.closePath();
          context.fill();

          //draw block
          context.fillStyle = '#333';
          context.fillRect(100,200,100,100);



          // Boundary Logic
            //if( x<0 || x>300) dx=-dx;
            //if( y<0 || y>300) dy=-dy;


            if(x>280){
            speedX=speedX * -1;
            }else if(y<20){
            speedY=speedY * -1;
            }else if(x<20){
            speedX=speedX * -1;
            }else if(y>380){
            speedY=speedY * -1;
            }else if( x>80 && y >180 && y <320) {
                speedY=speedY * -1;
            }else if( x<220 && y >180 && y <320) {
                speedY=speedY * -1;
            }else if( y>180 &&  x>80 && x<220) {
                speedX=speedX * -1;
            }else if( y<180 &&  x>80 && x<220) {
                speedX=speedX * -1;
            }

            x+=speedX;
            y+=speedY;

            ballCoordinates = x + 'x   ' + y + 'y ' + speedX + 'speedx    ' + speedY + 'speedy';
    }

</script>
<body onLoad="init();">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="400" style="background:red" >
  </canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Depends heavily on how you want to implement collisions. Using bounded boxes, bounded circles, pixel-perfect, PnP, Raycasting?

Comment: can you point me in the direction of examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/notearsgame/#toc-introduction

```
function collides(a, b) {
  return a.x < b.x + b.width &&
         a.x + a.width > b.x &&
         a.y < b.y + b.height &&
         a.y + a.height > b.y;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my [grapefruit](https://github.com/englercj/grapefruit) game engine I use a bounded-box system to detect collisions. I found a good question on [gamedev.stackexchange.com](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/586/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-work-out-2d-bounding-box-intersection) that helped me out and this is what I came up with:

```
intersects: function(entity) {
    return (Math.abs(this._hitboxMesh.position.x - entity._hitboxMesh.position.x) * 2 < (this.hitSize.x + entity.hitSize.x)) &&
            (Math.abs(this._hitboxMesh.position.y - entity._hitboxMesh.position.y) * 2 < (this.hitSize.y + entity.hitSize.y));
}
```

Basically the game loop will run this check on entities to see if they intersect, or collide. This is a method on an `Entity` object, so `this` refers to an `Entity` and so does the argument.

Answer (score 0):

a technique I have used in the past is to create a background buffer and give each object an id. Then when that object is drawn also draw it in on the background buffer making each pixels colour that id. While drawing on the background buffer check if any pixel is being drawn on a pixel that is not black (0) then it is a collision and the object you collided with is the colour of that pixel on the buffer.

Comment: that sounds great thank you - do have have a simple basic example I don't know what you mean my background buffer - do you mean create each object as a shape in the memory?

Comment: @Hello-World A background buffer is a canvas you draw on without actually showing it to the user. You can create it by creating a new canvas element (`var buffer = document.createElement("canvas")`) but never inserting it into the DOM of the website.

Comment: That's one way to do it, but as long as all objects have simple geometric shapes it would be more performance-efficient to use geometry to calculate intersections between them.